# Stability anda Lyapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I want to show that the null solution of the system $\frac{dx}{dt} = y$,$\frac{dy}{dt}= f(x)$, $((x(t), y(t)) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2)$ is stable, if the function f(x) satisfies the following

1. f is continuously differentiable
2. $f(x) = \left\{
       \begin{array}{ll}
           > 0  \mbox{ if }  x<0 \\
           = 0 \mbox{ if } x = 0 \\
           < 0 \mbox{ if } x >0
       \end{array}
   \right. $

I already prove that the the stability of the null solution x(t) = ψ(t) of the system:
$$\frac{dx_k}{dt} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial y_k} \mbox{ and } \frac{dy_k}{dt} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k}$$
For k = 1,...,n, $V=V(x,y) = V(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_n)$  which satisfies :

- V is a $C^2$-fonction
- V(0, 0) = 0.
- V(x, y) > 0 for (x,y) $\neq$ (0,0) ( or V(x,y) < 0 for (x,y) $\neq$ (0,0))
- ψ(t) =  (x(t), y(t)) ≡ (0, 0) is a solution

For that, I proved that V(x,y) or -V(x,y) is a Lyapunov function.

So now I think that I have to use this to prove my question, does anybody can help me?

Comment: Maybe this helps: you can find a constant of motion if you write the system as $\ddot x=f(x)$, multiply by $\dot x$, and integrate.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure to understand wat to do with it

Comment: I just know that if we use what I already prove we have $\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_k} = f(x)$ and so according to the assumption of V we have that V is C$^2$ that means f(x) has to be C$^1$

Comment: If you find a constant of motion and can show that it's level curves (which are orbits of the system) encircle the origin, then the origin must be a neutrally stable equilibrium point. (Think in term's of the system's phase portrait.)